# Syntax error while declaring string array in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

I have a shell script to convert WordPress Plugin readme files between `.txt` format and `.md`. It works perfectly fine in Mac terminal.

When I tried to run the shell script in Ubuntu, the following line

```
PLUGINMETA=("Contributors" "Donate link" "Donate Link" "Tags" "Requires at least" "Tested up to" "Stable tag" "License" "License URI")
```

throws the following syntax error.

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

That particular line is just declaring a list of string variables. I am not sure why it is generating a syntax error. Can someone kindly tell me which there is an error?

**Edit**:

The full source code of the file is available at https://github.com/sudar/wp-plugin-in-github/blob/master/readme-convertor.sh

I have picked up the relevant line and added above. Not sure if I have to include more lines.

Comment: I followed the syntax from here http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays and they don't seem to have commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Damn!!, I seem to be using the wrong shell. I was executing it with `sh`, instead of `bash`.

In mac, `sh` is mapped to `bash`, but it is not in Ubuntu.